# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I created a custom hook that returns my socket but in my homepage where i import it , it gives an error of
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit').[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBo4E.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sH63.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugo0j.png)

I tried to use the emit function but it gave this erorr.

Comment: Try using the socket.emit function in a useEffect

Comment: Don't use images. Instead, use text or code paste here with your question  @Padam Sinha